# Using socat to Tunnel/Proxy TCP want to split send/receive into separate files

Tags: tcp, proxy, http, socat

I'm using `socat` to dump plain TCP (e.g. HTTP) traffic:

```
socat -v tcp-listen:$PORT,reuseaddr,fork,keepalive tcp:$TARGET_HOST:$TARGET_PORT
```

At the moment all send and receive traffic is dumped into output stream. I'd like to split the send/receive into separate files.

#### Questions

- Is there a way to do that with `socat` itself and not using any external text processing tools?
- Is there a way to remove HTTP chunk delimiters as well from output or too much to ask?